# async await for virtual method

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

In our old synchronous application, we had the following in our base class:

```
public virtual bool ShouldSomethingHappen() => false;
```

So, the idea is that in the derived class, a call can be made to the DB to determine if something should happen.

So, when moving to awaited code, we first tried the following in the base class:

```
public virtual async Task<bool> ShouldSomethingHappen()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    return false;
}
```

This seemed to work fine when running the application, but it broke our integration tests (where we have many awaited calls)....we couldn't figure out why.

But, changing this to the following fixed the issue:

```
public virtual async Task<bool> ShouldSomethingHappen() => Task.FromResult(false);
```

So technically, what's the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: The definition does not need the `async` it could have been simplified to `public virtual Task<bool> ShouldSomethingHappen() => Task.FromResult(false);`. If there is nothing actually being awaited then there is no need to tag the call with `async`

Comment: Bear in mind - `async` is **not** part of the signature. It's fine to have a plain virtual method (non-`async`) that returns a `Task` and for some *derived* type to override that method with an `async` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that whatever happened in your integration tests *after* `await Task.Yield()` was not designed to work on a different thread. `Task.Yield()` causes method to continue running the rest of the method on another thread. When you use `Task.FromResult` you are returning already finished task. You are just returning completed task so it still happens on the same thread.

You can verify that by changing `Task.FromResult(false)` to <s>`Task.FromResult(false).ConfigureAwait(false)`.</s> `await Task.Delay(n).ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: Adding .ConfigureAwait(false) has no effect, but I think that determines whether the original context is packaged up and picked up by the "next" thread.  If Task.FromResult(...) is effectively synchronous, then it may have no effect.

Comment: @DrGriff Yea, that might be the case. You might try with something like `await Task.Delay(10).ConfigureAwait(false)` just to confirm.

Comment: `await Task.Delay(n).ConfigureAwait(false)` had the same effect as `await Task.Yield();`.

Comment: @DrGriff That's what I thought. What happens is, when you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` or `Task.Yield()`, `await` never returns to the thread that called it. If you show us one of these tests that fail or post any exception, we can figure out why they are unable to work on a different thread.

Comment: "Task.Yield() causes method to continue running the rest of the method on another thread." Do you have a reference to support that?

Comment: @KennethK. Well I do, but note that this statement is correct for this situation, meaning unit tests, because they run in environment without SynchronizationContext. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sr-latn-rs/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396): " If the current SynchronizationContext is non-null, it is treated as the current context. Otherwise, the task scheduler that is associated with the currently executing task is treated as the current context." The latter is true for this case.

Comment: @FCin I agree. When I first read your answer, though, it read like a blanket statement, and that did not seem correct. Applied only to this scenario, then I take no issue.